# Repository with simple cache in Kotlin

Tags: caching, kotlin, repository, android-room

I'm trying to implement a simple caching of a logged in user in a repository which is linked to a room database.

Here is the code of the repository

```
@Singleton
class UserRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val webservice: Webservice,
    private val userDao: UserDao
) {
    var user: User? = null  //simple cache of a currently logged in user
        private set

    init {
        user = null
    }

    fun getUser(userId: Int): LiveData<User> {
        if (user != null)
            return MutableLiveData<User>(user)
        val data = userDao.load(userId)
        //the value is always null because the load function is done async
        user = data.value
        return data
    }
}
```

And here is the UserDao

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("select * from user where id = :userId")
    fun load(userId: Int): LiveData<User>
}
```

User data is feched by a ViewModel like so

```
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
        repository: UserRepository
    ) : ViewModel() {

    val userId: Int = MainActivity.uid
    val user: LiveData<User> = repository.getUser(userId)
}
```

The data is fetched from the database and displayed correctly but the loaded user is never asigned to the cache because the loading is done async. Is it possible to add some listener to the load function?

I'm quite new to kotlin and android in general so if there are some better solutions for this kind of simple cache please advise.

Comment: There's a different problem in the above. `if (user != null) return MutableLiveData<User>(user)` should also be checking that `user.id == userId`. You also might want to limit the cache duration (or otherwise cleared) otherwise database changes to the current logged in user would never be visible.

Comment: Good points! But I guess those will be the next steps after I manage to set the user into cache.